# Google Chrome sometimes loads a new tab with only a quarter of the page visible

Tags: macos, google-chrome

This happens once a day or so, seemingly at random. It never happens in any other program. Refreshing the tab doesn't change anything. I have to close the tab and reopen it.

The whole page is there, and I can scroll it, but only the top left quarter will be visible at any one time.

Using OS X Yosemite, but the same problem occurred on OS X Mavericks. Chrome 37.0.2062.94